# Authentication a WCF Request via Client Certificate over HTTPS

Tags: wcf, configuration, ssl, x509certificate, transport-security

I've been struggling with the configuration for this blasted WCF service for the past week, and I'm slowing beginning to suspect that what I'm trying to do is just not possible, despite the documentation.

Quite simply, I want to have a WCF service require a client certificate (which the server will have in its cert store), and then access that identity with System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext. Additionally, this needs to use transport security.

Here's my server config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="requireCertificate" name="Server.CXPClient">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" name="wsHttpEndpoint" contract="PartnerComm.ContentXpert.Server.ICXPClient" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" name="mexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8371/Design_Time_Addresses/Server/CXPClient/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="requireCertificate">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CyberdyneIndustries" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here's my client config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
          transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://localhost:8371/Design_Time_Addresses/Server/CXPClient/"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior"
        contract="ContentXPertServer.ICXPClient" name="wsHttpEndpoint" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="CyberdyneIndustries" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The code all works perfectly when security mode='None' over http, but of course, there's no authentication, and nothing in System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext. I've tried dozens of variations on all of these elements, and it all ends up inevitably with the request throwing an exception "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

I'm using a self-signed cert "CyberdyneIndustries", whose CA cert I've added to the trusted CA store. The cert checks out when I view it. I've gone through the hell of http namespace management, and solved those problems as well. It simply looks like WCF doesn't really support this...please tell me I'm wrong.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I decided to try message security, to see if that would shed some light on the situation - it did, and I'm going to cut my losses and go with that. So, there's no definitive answer to this.

Implementing message security did, however, expose a BIG problem, and this may have been the root of the transport security problem. There is a piece of poison documentation from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650751.aspx

On this page, the command to create the self-signed cert is as follows:

> makecert -sk MyKeyName -iv
>   RootCaClientTest.pvk -n
>   "CN=tempClientcert" -ic
>   RootCaClientTest.cer -sr currentuser
>   -ss my -sky signature -pe

The argument "signature" should instead be "exchange". Once I regenerated all my certs, message security started working. One big takeaway from all of this is that if you're wanting to implement transport security, get message security working first, because the error messages you get from the system are much more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Does the SSL handshake succeed? Enable SChannel logging to troubleshoot the SSL layer. See this old KB article: [How to enable Schannel event logging in IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260729). Although is an KB for W2K and XP, the steps to enable SChannel logging are the same and still valid on newer systems. With the logging enabled you'll be able to determine why is SSL rejecting the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 3 years old, but for those who might still be interested...

I'm in the process of learning WCF (security among other things) and was able to get things working properly with netTcpBinding (presumably, this will work for WsHttpBindings as well) using Transport security mode with a  clientCredentialType="Certificate" (and, protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign", though that wasn't germane to the issue).

I did encounter the force connection close error from the server-side too, but discovered I was missing one piece of configuration. It's all working now.

Here's my server-side config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyNamespace.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9002/MyServer" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpCertSecurity" contract="MyNamespace.IMyService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="MyServiceCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TcpCertSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And my client-side configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9002/MyServer" binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="TcpCertSecurity" contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"
          behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
        <identity>
          <dns value="MyServiceCert" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TcpCertSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
            </serviceCertificate>
            <clientCertificate findValue="MyServiceCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I created a certificate chain for the server (self-signed Trusted Root certificate + a certificate built using that root) using the technique described [here](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/38/using-makecert-to-create-certificates-for-development) and stored both the Root cert and child cert in the certificate store of my server host machine. And, finally, I imported that server certificate + public key into the cert store on my client host machine (in LocalMachine/TrustedPeople).

Answer (score 0):

WsHttpBinding DOES support certificate authentication for transport security.

There can be a few things wrong:

1. Did you add **both** certificates to your store? CyberdyneIndustries as well a CA that you used to sign it? CA should be in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
2. Also, i've done this self-hosted, never in Visual Studio Dev server. Try to host your service in IIS at least. I am not sure if VS Dev server supports certificates.
3. Try to turn off service authentication. So the client doesn't have to authenticate the service. I don't know if you want this in your app or not but just for testing so we can rule that out

   ```
   <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
   <clientCredentials>
       <clientCertificate x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="CyberdyneIndustries" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
       <serviceCertificate>
           <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"/>
       </serviceCertificate>
   </clientCredentials>
   ```